# Don't want the full path of the file

Tags: php

I used `$path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value)` to get a path of a file.

If I echo $path it's going to print

> E:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\file.docx.

Is there any functions or ways that I could get **".\Folder2\Folder3"** as the value? Do I just trimmed it or is there a better way than that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on **what** you want to achieve with that path.

You can always use `dirname($path)` to get the path without the file name, but in your case, it seems that you also want to remove `E:\Folder1` from the path too.

If `E:\Folder1` is a default location on your system (like the main directory of your code, or a directory called `/uploads/`), what most people do is to store that path in a constant, so they can use it to trim the path without worrying. In pure PHP many people use something like this:

```
<?php
ROOT_PATH = realpath(__DIR__);
UPLOAD_PATH = ROOT_PATH . '/uploads/';
```

But if in the end you need to trim the path dynamically, you can provide some examples so we can think in a better approach :)